# Certain key combinations prevent key events in javascript

Tags: javascript

Working on an app that requires the ability to hold down multiple keys at once to trigger unique functions.

I've run into a situation where certain combinations of keys will prevent 'keydown' from being triggered.

Holding a horizontal row `1 > 2 > 3 > 4 > 5 > 6` or a vertical column `1 > Q > A > Z`

(6 keys appears to be the max the browser will recognise at once) will work however - if a user holds corner shape for example `1 > 2 > w` the events are prevented.

Can be demonstrated using this fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/B1KMusic/U5L2X/light/

Interestingly though this 'shape' of keys appears significant - `2 > 3 > W`and `3 > 4 > R` etc. will also be prevented.

Even if this shape is rotated across the keyboard the same shapes like: `C -> X -> S` and `N -> H -> J` will do the same.

If a gap is left and the corner is not 'connected' then the events will work properly `3 > E > D > V` - but if `C` is pressed this will not work.

What is going on here? Is this some intentional browser default to prevent key mashing?

---

*Edit: As the answer provided points out, this is a hardware issue so it makes sense to include hardware info: tested on a late 2013 Macbook Pro, apple stackexchange question confirms the answer here: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/47699/are-apple-keyboards-multi-key-rollover*

Comment: FWIW, a lot of keyboards are 6-key rollover; I doubt there is a 6-keydown limit in the browser.

Comment: I wonder if this is related to an n-key rollover situation. It could just be that the keyboard being used doesn't support recognizing that many keypresses at once. It's not an uncommon thing so I wonder if this could be it. http://goo.gl/38XwU1 http://goo.gl/Kv3eN

Comment: @Mathletics I think it depends on the keyboard and the arrangement of the switches. Some cheaper ones only support 3.

Comment: @Daved definitely; 6 is anecdotally common but my point was that the limitation is on the hardware side.

Comment: @Mathletics Got it. I agree and think it's hardware related. The second link I posted has a couple tests that are good for it. My current keyboard is a mech. gaming one. 6kro USB and nkro when PS2. Definitely varies based on hardware and interface.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a hardware limitation of your keyboard, not an issue with the browser. Most keyboards use a matrix arrangement for key switches, and hence cannot detect certain combinations of keys being pressed. The specific combinations which will and will not work are hardware-dependent, but in general, it is not safe to assume that more than two non-modifier keys can be pressed simultaneously.

Some gaming keyboards support [*n*-key rollover](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rollover_(key)) (that is, any number of keys being pressed at once), but these are rare.